# how to set css attribute to pseudo-class native js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Im try to set css attribute to element, which create by pseudo-class ":after"

I'm know how to get: 
`element = document.querySelector('.some-class');
var top = getComputedStyle(element, ':after').getPropertyValue("top")`
but object is returned by this method is read only

I try this:

```
element = document.querySelector('.some-class:after');
element.style.top = "100px";
```

but it not work...

Comment: You can't write inline styles directly to the pseudo element using JavaScript. However, one workaround is to use JavaScript to write styles to an inline <style> block in the header.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Answer (score 0):

*:after* means **pseudo-element**. You can't get it with JS, only CSS. So you need to try to use DOM element